# Notificação permanece na barra de status mesmo após o click

Tags: java, android, android-notification

Tenho uma aplicação no qual recebo notificações diárias, no entanto ao clicar nessa notificação, ela ainda permanece na minha barra de *status*. Estou usando o a classe [**NotificationCompat**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html) para criação destas notificações, no qual sempre que é lançada outra, esta mesmo sobrepõe a anterior. Abaixo segue o código que gera a notificação:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
    context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

builder.setContentTitle("Title");

builder.setContentText("Content of notification");

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.
     getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Como faço para que ao clicar na notificação ela não permaneça mais na barra de *status*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tente da seguinte forma:

```
builder.setAutoCancel (true);
```

Além disso, embora não seja realmente necessário, se você realmente deseja usar `FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL`, basta adicioná-lo:

```
 Notification notification=  builder.build();
 notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
 notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Segundo a documentação:

**[setAutoCancel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setAutoCancel(boolean))**

> Tornar esta notificação automaticamente ignorada quando o usuário a
>   toca. O conjunto PendingIntent com setDeleteIntent (PendingIntent)
>   será enviado quando isso acontecer.

**[FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL)**

> Campo sinalizador que deve ser definido se a notificação deve ser
>   cancelada quando ele é clicado pelo usuário.

[FONTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120821/remove-notification-after-clicking)

Comment: Mas qual seria a diferença entre setAutoCancel e FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL?

Comment: Já coloquei o +1 porque já tinha resolvido aqui com a primeira opção faz horas. Agora não entendi porque negativaram a pergunta.

Comment: Pra negativar tem vários! Pra responder poucos! Hahahaha